# How should i make infinte ground ?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a simplified version of crazy taxi . For the first step i need to make an infinite ground . I'VE searched online but couldn't find any examples .
Can i find any example of how to do this ?

Comment: Let's assume - Draw distance of 1,000 units. So, you'll only ever need to draw 2,000 square units of ground at any given time (assuming player in center). So, you could have a 2,000 square unit "tile". You would only ever need to have 9 of these in the scene at any time (with the player in the center tile). As the player moves across the center tile to an edge tile, you would remove the tiles from the farthest edge from the player and add them to the edge ahead of the player.

Comment: What you are looking for is called chunks. You divide visible portion of terrain into chunks and load them depending on players position. Basically what @ThomasCook described.

Comment: If you don't have repeating terrain (i.e. you can't just keep 9 tile references in memory because you have 100's of different tiles - image Skyrim)then you could look into LoadAsync (which lets you load resources on a background thread).

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAsync.html

Also, this question is probably more suitable for GameDevExchange.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhTPxrJICVg&list=PLLH3mUGkfFCXQcNBz_FZDpqJfQlupTznd

N3K makes an infinite runner in Subway Surfers style, meaning ground coming from the back and going towards the camera.

The above link is to his tutorial series.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question I try to give a very simplified answer to get you going.

To create endless road you need some sort of procedural function that generates corners for your track. If you do not need to backtrack you can cook something up yourself like (in X distance turn X degrees to the right). If you do need to backtrack you need something like perlin/simplex noise that always generates the same value based on 1 or more other values. You could use total distance to get the curve in the road.

You simply keep generating the world on the fly and unload pieces of the world you don't need any more. If the player can alter the world like destroying street furniture or leaving skitmarks you need to implement a chunk system. When you backtrack and generate a cerain part of the world with your procedural function you can have permanent changes the player made in that specific part by saving and loading to the chunk. Much like Minecraft does it actually.